# MVC using viewmodel derived from base viewmodel used in another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This is for an asp.net mvc3 project. I have two views and their own corresponding viewmodels.

Home.aspx has a viewmodel HomeVM

HomeChild.aspx has a viewmodel as HomeChildVM.

Now HomeChildVM is derived from HomeVM and has a few properties more that are used in its own view. My controller has one action method that returns the Home view and another action method that returns the HomeChild view. Both these action methods call one business method that returns a type as HomeVM. Then my action methods return the same to the aspx view.

```
return View(objHomeVM);
```

Now, instead of writing another business method and repeating all the code all over again just to return another viewmodel type ie HomeChildVM, I am assigning the properties of objHomeVM to objHomeChildVM one by one like so:

```
 objHomeChildVM.prop1 = objHomeVM.prop1;
 objHomeChildVM.prop2 = objHomeVM.prop2;
```

and then returning it:

```
 return View(objHomeChildVM);
```

Is there a better way to do this than by assigning properties one by one? I feel this is too primitive a way, unless this is the only way to do it.

HomeChild.aspx currently has this page directive

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomeChildVM>" %>
```

If I change that to HomeVM then I wont be able to use the extra properties that HomeChildVM has which are only specific to HomeChild.aspx page.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: You tagged this question as ASP.NET MVC3, but it looks like you are using a previous version of MVC?  Try adding those tags as well.

Comment: If it is an MVC3 project then I would suggest you use views ending with .cshtml. Make use of the view start file to specify your master pages for your views. The code looks different, you don't use <%%> any more but @.

Comment: Can you please clairify what you mean by _derived_? Does the HomeChildVM inherit from HomeVM (`public class HomeChildVM : HomeVM`) or does HomeChildVM just have a similar set of properties as HomeVM?

Comment: Adrian: yes public class HomeChildVM : HomeVM is what I meant by derived, plus, HomeChildVM has a few more properties of its own.

Comment: Brendan: If I had a choice I would have, but this is a project I joined midway, so its too late to suggest those changes now. Besides, I've always wondered, what is the actual benefit of using @ over using <% %>.. the only benefit I see is more examples out there using @ , but again thats just a minor inconvenience..

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on your view models.  I would create a view model for both views, even though some of the properties are used in both.  What are you going to do if you have to remove one of the properties in HomeVM?  Then HomeChildVM falls apart.

Getting back to your question on assigning the properties one by one..  I would suggest you look at [Auto Mapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).  It takes care of mapping the properties between objects for you.

**UPDATED**

Once you have your types, and a reference to AutoMapper, you can create a map for the two types:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();  // Create the map
```

The type on the left is the source type, and the type on the right is the destination type. To perform a mapping, use the Map method:

```
CustomerDto dto = Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>(customer);
```

Here is some sample code that you could write/use to map between 2 objects:

```
public static Customer Map(CustomerEntity entity)
{
     return new Customer
     {
          CustomerId = entity.CustomerId,
          Company = entity.CompanyName,
          City = entity.City,
          Country = entity.Country
     };
}
```

And then to use it would look something like this:

```
Mapper.Map(customer);
```

Comment: Good point in other scenarios. but in this situation there is practically no chance of that being a problem. the child view is an extension of the home view. The parent view has a table displaying records. The child view adds some filter criteria to the same view and some other additional view details that are related to a totally different area of the application. If anything goes out from the parent it goes out from the child too.

Comment: so auto-mapper is the only way? I was looking at something native to c#

Comment: Automapper is all I can think of. If you don't want to use then I would suggest writing it. Automappper makes you code much less. You can imagine all the code if your view model has 30 properties. With Automapper you can map everyrhing in a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Thanks will consider it. But I thought with these two classes, one being inherited from another would have an in-built .net way to cast one as another..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating the required ViewModel outside the business method and then passing a reference of the ViewModel into your business method, as a type of HomeVM, to be populated? ie:

```
public ActionResult HomeAction()
{
   HomeVM objHomeVM = new HomeVM();

   BusinessMethod(objHomeVM);

   return View(objHomeVM);
}

public ActionResult HomeChildAction()
{
   HomeChildVM objHomeChildVM = new HomeChildVM();

   BusinessMethod(objHomeChildVM);

   return View(objHomeChildVM);
}

private void BusinessMethod(HomeVM objHomeVM)
{
   ...
   objHomeVM.prop1 = prop1;
   objHomeVM.prop2 = prop1;
   ...
}
```

Remember ViewModels are simply normal objects. The only thing special about them is that they are called ViewModels.

Comment: that wont work. The business method works internally on an object of type objHomeVM and also returns objHomeVM. for it to be able to return another type based on some parameters would mean that I would have to do it the old fashioned way using reflection or something to determine the type that was passed in and accordingly set that particular type only and return that same type that was passed in. This would involve redoing and retesting that particular business method all over again. I just wanted to extend existing fucntionality